# I want to get data into my checkout page from multiple table according it's page id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I want to get values into my checkout page according to its page id.How can I get it???

I have 3 buttons and their id into a page BTW their three different table data.

```
<a href="chekout.php?v=<?= $total_row['gfx_id'];?>" ">Buy Now</a>
<a href="chekout.php?v=<?= $total_row['frontend_id'];?>" >Buy Now</a>
<a href="chekout.php?v=<?= $total_row['backend_id'];?>" >Buy Now</a>
```

Now I want to get their id data into my checkout page.I just managed to get one table data here is it `

```
$id=$_GET['v'];
$sel="SELECT * FROM gfx WHERE gfx_id='$id' ";
$qri_res=mysqli_query($con,$sel);`
```

How can I get another 2 data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44277503/7290255

Comment: Do you want to get the ID's of all these three "Buy Now" button once on the chechout page?

Comment: yeah, can tell me how can I write the condition code at my checkout page to get there vlaue

Comment: All done bro thanks for comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send other parameter

```
<a href="chekout.php?v=<?= $total_row['gfx_id'];?>&flag=1" ">Buy Now</a>
<a href="chekout.php?v=<?= $total_row['frontend_id'];?>&flag=2" >Buy Now</a>
<a href="chekout.php?v=<?= $total_row['backend_id'];?>&flag=3" >Buy Now</a>
```

And get flag variable and fire query according to flag.

Comment: Got it! bro, how can I show it to my checkout page I mean what condition should I apply at checkout page?

Comment: if you get flag=1 then fire query and display view for gfx_id,
if you get flag=2 then fire query and display view for frontend_id
and if you get flag=3 then fire query and display view for backend_id

Comment: For flag=1
`if($_GET['flag']==1)
{
           $id=$_GET['v'];
           $sel="SELECT * FROM gfx WHERE gfx_id='$id' ";
           $qri_res=mysqli_query($con,$sel);
}`